# XUL Runner Log HTTP Requests Python

Tags: python, http, xul, xulrunner

Looking for some help to log HTTP requests for a given page.

Essentially I'm looking at running a Ubuntu instance to log HTTP requests from a given page and parse them out to the user. I'd like to use a Python Web App client side.

Workflow is :

User types in URL > App takes in Requests > XULRunner "does something" > Python App returns cookies set for the given URL.

Looking for some pointers around the process "XULRunner does something"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use a [`<browser type="content">` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/browser) in XULRunner and use `browser.addProgressListener()` to add a [web progress listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners). With the progress listener you will be able to track all requests (calls to `onStateChange` with `aFlag` containing `STATE_IS_REQUEST` flag). The progress listener can then read out the requested address (`aRequest.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIChannel).URI.spec`) and log it. If `aFlag` contains `STATE_STOP` flag then you can also read out response headers (`aRequest.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel).getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")`). Calling `browser.loadURI()` actually starts loading the page.